# Python export csv with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem after exporting the dataframes into a csv file.

```
start = __datetime(startTime)  
end = __datetime(endTime)
delta = end - start
durationList.append(delta)

dataFrame = {"Duration": durationList}
outPutFile = pd.DataFrame(dataFrame, columns=["Duration"])
outPutFile.to_csv('Extract data.csv', index=False)
print(outPutFile)
```

Printing result:

```
          Duration  
0  00:00:00.001000  
1  00:00:00.002000  
2  00:00:00.205000
```

Export result:

```
Duration
0 days 00:00:00.001000000
0 days 00:00:00.002000000
0 days 00:00:00.205000000
```

I am not sure why format of export data has been changed, I do not want to have the number of days. I have tried to reformat in excel but it doesn't work. Also, I have tried `.to_pickle(), parse_dates, astype`, but it still can't be solved.
For start and end time is founded with regex, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to convert your series to a `datetime` object, then use `pd.Series.dt.strftime`.

CSV files are not type sensitive, so converting to string is a reliable way of ensuring your output is in the format you expect.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Duration': ['00:00:00.001000', '00:00:00.002000', '00:00:00.205000']})

df['Duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Duration'])

df['DurationStr'] = (df['Duration'] + pd.Timestamp('20180101')).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S:%f')

print(df)

#          Duration      DurationStr
# 0 00:00:00.001000  00:00:00:001000
# 1 00:00:00.002000  00:00:00:002000
# 2 00:00:00.205000  00:00:00:205000

print(df.dtypes)

# Duration       timedelta64[ns]
# DurationStr             object
# dtype: object
```

Comment: Is it possible to just have "DurationStr"? I have tried to remove "df['Duration'] + ", but it will have AttributeError. I need the values from "DurationStr" only. Thank you.

Comment: Sure just change the last line to `df['Duration'] = ...` You are left with a single string column.